# How to write this sql query into laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have a query i'm trying to use to optimize my old queries because they weren't efficient enough but I'm having trouble looking for eloquent cheat sheets.

Here is my query:

select * from o inner join t on o.id = t.oid where t.wid in(1,2,3,4)

Comment: Please mark the correct answer for you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must read about [`relationships`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

You can do it with a simple relationship:

```
class Transaction extends Eloquent {
     /**
     * Return the relationship
     **/
     public function order(){
            // The Transaction belongs to Order.
            // So, the Transaction has a order_id reference
            return $this->belongsTo('Order');
     }
}

class Order extends Eloquent {
     /**
     * Return the relationship
     **/
     public function transaction(){
            // Define the relationship. Order has one Transaction
            // So, the table Transaction has a order_id reference.
            return $this->hasOne('Transaction');
     }
}

/**
/* In your controller:
**/
// Return the Transaction where id is 1, 2, 3 or 4.
$transaction = Transaction::whereIn('waypoint_id', array(1,2,3,4) )->get();
// Get the Order owner of the Transaction
$order = $transaction->order;

echo $order->id; // It prints the Order id
echo $transaction->id; // It prints the Transaction id
```

Also you can get the `Transaction` from a `Order` so:

```
$order = Order::find(1); // Get the order with id 1
$transaction = $order->transaction; // Get the transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$output = DB::table('orders as od')
        ->join('transactions as tr', 'od.id', '=', 'tr.order_id')
        ->whereIn('tr.waypoint_id', array(1,2,3,4))
        ->get();

print_r($output);   // it will return an array of object
```

reference: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins